# Command line program for Windows 8.x/10 to split a file at given bytes

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I'm looking for a command line utility that I can use in a batch file to split binary files in two at a specified point. For example, I have hundreds of files with the same size, let's say 1GB (1073741824 bytes), and I want to discard the first 100MB (104857600 bytes) and keep the remaining 924MB (968884224 bytes). It can be a program installed to the system as long as it does the job when called from a batch file, but a portable/independent utility would be preferred.

GSplit 3 can do it in the GUI with the option "I want to define the size for each piece file myself", it might be doable in the command line but it requires profiles and scripts and I got lost in the mess. Maybe there's an easier tool to do it?

Comment: What is the objective of removing part of a file? Would it still work after removing a chunk?

Comment: You can maybe use `dd skip=... count=...` from WSL, GnuWin, unxutils or any similar source.

Comment: Yes, it would still "work", because it's not an executable, the data inside is spit in 2 contents and cutting the 1st one makes the 2nd one usable for other programs. I have read about dd and I'll try it if no portable option is found.

Comment: I found it! It's dd but for Win32, so it's portable and I don't need to install GnuWin. Thanks for suggesting dd, it led me to looking for it as an individual program. This is the one I used: http://www.chrysocome.net/dd